# How to repair the plastic in a freezer?

Tags: refrigerator, plastic, freezer

How to repair the plastic in a freezer? (or refrigerator)

This is a chest freezer with a lift up lid (door). The lid collected ice on the inside (between the insulation and plastic trim) until the weight ripped the inside lid (trim) from the door. The perimeter of the inside lid is held in place by plastic rivets. The perimeter was ripped at all the rivet locations. What is this plastic and can I buy strips to overlay and re-rivet the trim back on? {there is a light in it and I'd really like to repair it.}

Comment: Photos and/or model information, please. It's hard to give good answers with such a vague description. It's possible that the panel is repairable.

Comment: Yep.  Pics and/or model.  Depending on age, you could just get a replacement part from Partselect or similar.

Comment: Sounds like a job for some 2-part epoxy.